# Why my code error? find call value in R code

Tags: r, computational-statistics

this is my code
whats miss? Im confused why my code error
please help me
this code like black-scholes but in geske formula

Values Call = VT1*N(d1)-K2*exp(-r*(T2-T1))*N(d2)

N=distribution normal

d1=(log(VT1/K2)+((r+(1/2) x sigmaˆ2/2) x (T2-T1))/(sigma x sqrt(T2-T1)))

d2=d1-(sigma*sqrt(T2-T1))

thats the formula

```
> Call_On_Call<-function(VT1,K1,K2,r,sigma,T2,T1)
+ {
+ 
+ #VT1    ...   initial stock price
+ #T1    ... maturity of the compound option
+ #K1    ... strike of the compound option
+ #T2     ... maturity of the underlying option
+ #K2     ... strike of the underlying option
+ #r     ... interest rate
+ #sigma ... volatiliy

+ #Valuescall

+ d1<−(log(VT1/K2)+((r+(1/2)*sigmaˆ2/2)∗(T2-T1))/(sigma*sqrt(T2-T1));
Error: unexpected input in:
"
d1<-(log(VT1/K2)+((r+(1/2)*sigmaˆ"
> d2<-d1-(sigma*sqrt(T2-T1));
Error: object 'd1' not found
> 
> valuescall<-VT1*pnorm(d1)-K2*exp(-r*(T2-T1))*pnorm(d2);
Error: object 'VT1' not found
> 
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 problems that I can see in your definition of `d1`:

- strange character `ˆ` instead of `^`
- missing `)` at the end

So your d1 should be defined like this:

```
d1<−(log(VT1/K2)+((r+(1/2)*sigma^2/2)∗(T2-T1))/(sigma*sqrt(T2-T1)));
```

Comment: thank you sir @haroldship
can I ask one more question??

Comment: @RevaldoMario yes you can ask for sure